# Regular Expression option for 3 or less characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression below that works for a string example like:

- `MCCOY 3H L24 FINAL 02-28-2012.dwg` or
- `SMITH-JOHNSON 5H R32 FINAL 05-26-2012.dwg`

But now I'm trying to figure out how to change the regular expression to work for the examples above if they were like:

- `MCCOY 3H L-ABC FINAL 02-28-2012.dwg` or
- `SMITH-JOHNSON 5H R-123 FINAL 05-26-2012.dwg`

They can also be like

- `MCCOY 3H L-C2 FINAL 02-28-2012.dwg` or
- `SMITH-JOHNSON 5H R-2 FINAL 05-26-2012.dwg`

So to sum this up, that middle section will always have a **Alphabetic character followed by a Dash** and then it could have **as much as 3 numbers or alphabetic characters** or **as few as 1 number or alphabetic character**.

```
"^[a-z]+(?:[ -][a-z]+)*\s+\d+[a-z]\s+[a-z]\d+\s+[a-z]+\s+\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\.dwg$"
```

Comment: You have a problem -> you think regex. Now you have two problems! ;-) - sorry, couldn't stop myself... (http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: @JakubKonecki - At least link to the source of the quote.

Comment: @Oded - It could [take a long time](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) to figure that source out...

Comment: What are you trying to do with the regex, that is - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `[a-z-]` would add `-` to the character class to match on (if a character class starts or ends with `-` it gets included).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\w{1,3}
```

matches 1 to 3 alphanumeric characters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#quantifiers

Comment: \w{,3} for less than or equal to 3

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add a `(?i)` to get this to work because `[a-z]` does not match upper-case characters - at least in the regexp engines I normally use :) So I arrived at this:

```
(?i)^[a-z]+(?:[ -][a-z]+)*\s+\d+[a-z]\s+[a-z]-\w{1,3}\s+[a-z]+\s+\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\.dwg
```

[Try it yourself on Regexr](http://regexr.com?322v7).

**Edit:** As @Oded made me notice, the stars in the question are not part of the input strings - removed and updated Regexr link.

Comment: I believe the `**` are an attempt to make the characters within **bold**. The issue the OP is trying to solve is matching the `-`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex that will return all the fields separately:

```
^(?<Customer>.*?)\s+?(?<Id1>[\-a-z0-9]*?)\s+?(?<Id2>[\-a-z0-9]*?)\s+?FINAL\s+?(?<Date>[\-0-9]{10})\.dwg$
```

Fields description:

- **Customer**: `MCCOY`, `SMITH-JOHNSON`, `JAKE MCCOY`
- **Id1**: `5H`, `3H`
- **Id2**: `L24`, `R32`, `L-ABC`, `R-123`, `L-C2`
- **Date**: `02-28-2012`, `05-26-2012`

Tested on:

```
MCCOY         3H L24   FINAL 02-28-2012.dwg
SMITH-JOHNSON 5H R32   FINAL 05-26-2012.dwg
JAKE MCCOY    3H L-ABC FINAL 02-28-2012.dwg
SMITH-JOHNSON 5H R-123 FINAL 05-26-2012.dwg
MCCOY         3H L-C2  FINAL 02-28-2012.dwg
SMITH-JOHNSON 5H R-2   FINAL 05-26-2012.dwg
```